# Signing data with private key in ruby's OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, openssl, md5, rsa, digest

I have native openssl utilitiy command

```
openssl dgst -sign mtscert.pem -out KK_0.txt -md5 svertka.txt
```

And i need to 'convert' it to ruby's OpenSSL. When i do it this way

```
keypair = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("somecert_with_keys.pem"), "somepass")
keypair.sign(OpenSSL::Digest::MD5.new, File.read("input.txt"))
```

I get a little different code.
Native openssl gives:

```
,\xFC^\x99\xE1\xFB\xE7\r\u0014'2n\xB5A\x8C;\xFF<\x88=\x81\fX\x9F\x8E\xD8&^\u001DD\xBCӳ\xFE\xD4\xC6r6xn²\xE9D\xB3Y\xA0\xF6\xAB\rV\u0012w\u0014U\u000F\xA2\xFC\xA1[O\xAA\xCEB\xBD\x97C\xB5\xA3E\xE65\xADYq\xC5ӽ\r.\xA2\xE4\x86\u0016p\u000EݫSs\xA4\x9B\xD8\u0012\x80P^\xF4\x896\xC2\u001F\xC0\xBF>5\xEF[ʎ\xFD\xAE;p\x88|9a+\x89\xC1\u001Ej\xBA\xDD\xEB\u001D\xC8
```

Ruby's OpenSSL:

```
,\xFC^\x99\xE1\xFB\xE7\r\x14'2n\xB5A\x8C;\xFF<\x88=\x81\fX\x9F\x8E\xD8&^\x1DD\xBC\xD3\xB3\xFE\xD4\xC6r6xn\xC2\xB2\xE9D\xB3Y\xA0\xF6\xAB\rV\x12w\x14U\x0F\xA2\xFC\xA1[O\xAA\xCEB\xBD\x97C\xB5\xA3E\xE65\xADYq\xC5\xD3\xBD\r.\xA2\xE4\x86\x16p\x0E\xDD\xABSs\xA4\x9B\xD8\x12\x80P^\xF4\x896\xC2\x1F\xC0\xBF>5\xEF[\xCA\x8E\xFD\xAE;p\x88|9a+\x89\xC1\x1Ej\xBA\xDD\xEB\x1D\xC8
```

Comment: Two leading zeros in a literal string is no difference. And please avoid MD5 for security when you can. It has been proven very weak, and has a lot of collision attack possibilities.

Comment: @Linuxios is right. The only differences I noticed were in the way the data was presented (formatted), the underlying bits look to be the same. It looks different because you're printing out binary data as a string and it's being formatted differently. If you could output it as hex, it should be exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it's requirements of the black box api. The answer was, that ruby's openssl use ASCII to display special characters, and native openssl - UTF-8. I solved my problem by applying force_encoding('UTF-8') to the string with signature.